# CALayer inner border corner radius

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, calayer

I have a UITextView where I set the border width, border color, and corner radius properties on its layer, and the outside looks great. However, the inner part of the border doesn't have rounded corners like the outer part, and it looks kind of funny. Is there a way to round the inner corners of the border?

Edit:
Here's the code I used in the `initWithFrame:` method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xdedede);
        self.layer.cornerRadius = kTextFieldCornerRadius;
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xD4974C).CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12.0f];
        [self setClipsToBounds:YES];
        [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And here's a screenshot of what it looks like now: [image]

Notice the outer corners are rounded as expected, but the inner corners of the border are pointed rather than rounded. That's what I'm trying to fix. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show your code and snapshot of the textview

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to set this,

```
[txtView       setClipsToBounds:YES]; //Confirms subviews are confined to the bounds of the view
[txtView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES]; //Confirms sublayers are clipped to the layer’s bounds
```

**EDIT**

Probably the value of kTextFieldCornerRadius is set to low in your case.

If I set `kTextFieldCornerRadius = 7;` see I can get perfect output.

[image]

try to increase your radius value.

Comment: I had imported QuartzCore, and tried changing the corner radius, and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Import `QuartzCore` framework and add the following lines of code :

***OBJECTIVE - C***

```
UIView *yourView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 430)];
yourView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
yourView.layer.borderWidth = 10.0f;
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0f;

[yourView setClipsToBounds:YES];
[yourView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

***SWIFT - 3.0.1 (playground code)***

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

 import UIKit
 import PlaygroundSupport
 import QuartzCore

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 375.0, height: 100.0))

containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
containerView.layer.borderWidth = 10
containerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
containerView.clipsToBounds = true
containerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20

 PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
 PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

***OUTPUT :***

[image: OUTPUT :]

***IMPORTANT:***

Make sure the `cornerRadius` is greater than the `borderWidth` . Else you will not be able to see the difference.